# models/package-info.class with Hibernate @FilterDef annotation not being picked by Play1 app on Heroku

Tags: java, hibernate, heroku, annotations, playframework-1.x

When I run my application in dev mode on my local machine using OracleJDK8 and Play v1.3.1-56-gac02587 a @FilterDef annotation defined in models/package-info.class is picked up correctly and the application executes as expected.

The models/package-info.java is defined as follows:

```
@FilterDef(name="softDelete", defaultCondition="(deleteTimestamp is null or deleteTimestamp > now())")

package models;

import org.hibernate.annotations.FilterDef;
```

However when I deploy the application to Heroku running OpenJDK8 and the same Play version where it is running in production mode I get the following exception. It appears that the default filter condition defined in the package level @FilterDef annotation is not being picked indicating that the models/package-info.class is not being loaded successfully.

```
11-09-15 17:55:51,699 [main] ERROR play
Can't start in PROD mode with errors
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Unable to build EntityManagerFactory
        at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:925)
        at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:900)
        at play.db.jpa.JPAPlugin.onApplicationStart(JPAPlugin.java:208)
        at play.plugins.PluginCollection.onApplicationStart(PluginCollection.java:515)
        at play.Play.start(Play.java:537)
        at play.Play.init(Play.java:309)
        at play.server.Server.main(Server.java:160)
Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: no filter condition found for filter softDelete in CommunityMember
        at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.EntityBinder.bindEntity(EntityBinder.java:388)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.bindClass(AnnotationBinder.java:602)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration$MetadataSourceQueue.processAnnotatedClassesQueue(Configuration.java:3625)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration$MetadataSourceQueue.processMetadata(Configuration.java:3579)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.secondPassCompile(Configuration.java:1381)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1786)
        at org.hibernate.ejb.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.<init>(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:96)
        at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:918)
        ... 6 more
```

The difference appears to be that Heroku is running the application in production mode with precompiled classes. When I simulate that locally by using "play run -Dprecompiled=true" I get the same exception...

```
$ play-13x run -Dprecompiled=true
~        _            _ 
~  _ __ | | __ _ _  _| |
~ | '_ \| |/ _' | || |_|
~ |  __/|_|\____|\__ (_)
~ |_|            |__/   
~
~ play! 1.3.x-1.3.1-43-g3d16160, https://www.playframework.com
~
~ Ctrl+C to stop
~ 
~ using java version "1.8.0_25"
objc[75867]: Class JavaLaunchHelper is implemented in both /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_25.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java and /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_25.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/libinstrument.dylib. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 8000
13:38:05,265 [main] INFO  ~ Starting
:: loading settings :: url = jar:file:/usr/local/play-1.3.x-1.3.1-43-g3d16160/framework/lib/ivy-2.4.0.jar!/org/apache/ivy/core/settings/ivysettings.xml
13:38:05,543 [main] INFO  ~ Module crud is available (/usr/local/play-1.3.x-1.3.1-43-g3d16160/modules/crud)
13:38:05,543 [main] INFO  ~ Module fastergt is available (/Users/chris/git/PTAsocial-MVP/modules/fastergt-1.8)
13:38:05,543 [main] INFO  ~ Module db is available (/Users/chris/git/PTAsocial-MVP/modules/db-1.1.2)
13:38:05,544 [main] INFO  ~ Module accesslog is available (/Users/chris/git/PTAsocial-MVP/modules/accesslog-1.2)
13:38:05,544 [main] INFO  ~ Module deadbolt is available (/Users/chris/git/PTAsocial-MVP/modules/deadbolt-1.5.4)
13:38:05,544 [main] INFO  ~ Module coffee is available (/Users/chris/git/PTAsocial-MVP/modules/coffee-1.0)
13:38:05,544 [main] INFO  ~ Module securesocial is available (/Users/chris/git/PTAsocial-MVP/modules/securesocial-0.2.7)
13:38:05,544 [main] INFO  ~ Module morphia is available (/Users/chris/git/PTAsocial-MVP/modules/morphia-1.5.0a)
13:38:05,760 [main] INFO  ~ Loaded image cleaner plugin
13:38:06,817 [main] INFO  ~ Application is precompiled
13:38:06,826 [main] DEBUG ~ MorphiaPlugin-1.5.0> reading configuration
13:38:08,072 [main] INFO  ~ Connected to jdbc:h2:mem:play;MODE=MYSQL for default
13:38:08,253 [main] INFO  ~ JPA -> Adding package: models
13:38:08,526 [main] ERROR ~ Can't start in PROD mode with errors
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Unable to build EntityManagerFactory
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:925)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:900)
    at play.db.jpa.JPAPlugin.onApplicationStart(JPAPlugin.java:208)
    at play.plugins.PluginCollection.onApplicationStart(PluginCollection.java:515)
    at play.Play.start(Play.java:537)
    at play.Play.init(Play.java:309)
    at play.server.Server.main(Server.java:160)
Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: no filter condition found for filter softDelete in CommunityMember
    at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.EntityBinder.bindEntity(EntityBinder.java:388)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.bindClass(AnnotationBinder.java:602)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration$MetadataSourceQueue.processAnnotatedClassesQueue(Configuration.java:3625)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration$MetadataSourceQueue.processMetadata(Configuration.java:3579)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.secondPassCompile(Configuration.java:1381)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1786)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.<init>(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:96)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:918)
    ... 6 more
```

This issue was raised before and there was a patch but it seems to be broken again. Maybe something to do with JDK8?

[#1310: package-info.java is not loaded when running from precompiled sources](https://play.lighthouseapp.com/projects/57987/tickets/1310-package-infojava-is-not-loaded-when-running-from-precompiled-sources)

I've stepped through ApplicationClassloader.loadApplicationClass(String name) in both non-precompiled and precompiled modes but I can't see any effective difference in the loaded class for models/package-info.java

Comment: When you run the app locally, are you using the `--%prod` option? I know you said you run in in PROD mode, but i'm curious what the  mechanism is. Also, can you check the `models/package-info.class` exists on heroku by running `$ heroku run ls models/package-info.class`?

Comment: ack, just saw you already have the `heroku run` command there...

Comment: @codefinger I'm not strictly running --%prod but running with a configuration that includes "application.mode=prod". Is there some special magic for --%prod above and beyond?

Comment: @codefinger I've updated my original question because I've discovered that to properly simulate the Heroku production deployment you need to call Play locally with -Dprecompiled=true and then I get the same exception locally. Unfortunately still not any closer to finding out what is broken in the Play class loading with precompiled classes.